# Java Apache DBCP2 Connection Pool Exceeding Maximum Number of Connections when Multithreaded

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons-dbcp

I have created a database connection pool using the Apache DBCP2 library. It connects successfully to the database. Part of the configuration is shown below:

```
pool = new BasicDataSource();
pool.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
pool.setInitialSize(1);
pool.setMaxTotal(2);
```

To test that the maximum number of connections is obeyed, I set up an executor service with 10 threads, where each thread obtains a connection using `pool.getConnection()` and executes the SQL statement `SELECT SLEEP(5)`.

As the maximum number of connections is 2, I expected this test to take approximately 25 seconds as only two threads can execute the command at a time. However, the pool gives all the threads a connection so the test only takes approximately 5 seconds.

Is `BasicDataSource` not thread safe? Or if it is, how do I configure it to block the other threads when the maximum number of connections are in use?

Comment: Are you catching and logging all possible exceptions? Maybe the pool throws an exception instead of blocking when no more connections can be had.

Comment: Yes - no exceptions are being suppressed. Each thread executes the SQL statement successfully so the pool is giving out valid connections, just too many of them at a time!

Comment: soarjay. did you find the cause and solution.